# Ionic $http requests fail on device, not serve

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 1 app which uses $http requests. When I run `ionic serve` the browser acts fine. When I run `android build` and run on a device al of my http requests fail. (I am not using localhost, I am using an external server)

The networks shows the request as failed with no response. If I run the exact request through POSTMAN I receive a response.

If I use a break point I can see the response is returned with status code -1.

I have tried upgrading all of my plugins and adding `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />` with no luck.

Any ideas what could be going on?

`ionic info`:
    cli packages:

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.14.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.14.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : android 5.2.2
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.3

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.1.7
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.0 
    ios-sim           : 5.0.8 
    Node              : v6.11.0
    npm               : 5.5.1 
    OS                : OS X El Capitan
    Xcode             : Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014 

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Comment: what's the target url ? Is it localhost or something else ?

Comment: My target URL is to an actual external server (not localhost) @sheplu

Comment: did you add the permission ? <uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> into platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: "Minus one" (SO won't let me type it) usually means that it didn't actually talk to the server. No server actually returns a "minus one" response code.

Comment: That's what I assumed, I have even tried ngrok so I could debug and never got a ping. (Double checking user permissions now)

Comment: @sheplu You are correct. The permissions were somehow removed during an automated build process. Thank you!

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Getting the same issue on my end now.